# Scraping with RSelenium and understanding html tags

Tags: r, selenium

I've been learning how to scrape the web using `RSelenium` by trying to gather sports data. I have a difficult time understanding how to get certain elements based on tags. In the following example, I get the player names that I want, but I only get the top 28. I don't understand why, since when I inspect lower elements, they have similar xpaths. Example:

```
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

# URL 
rotoURL = as.character("https://rotogrinders.com/lineuphq/nba?site=draftkings")

# Start remote driver
remDrall <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", verbose = F)
remDr <- remDrall$client
remDr$open(silent = TRUE)
Sys.sleep(1)

# Go to URL
remDr$navigate(rotoURL)
Sys.sleep(3)

# Get player names and clean
plyrNms <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//*[@id='primary-pane']/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div")
plyrNmsText <- plyrNms$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
plyrNmsClean <- htmlTreeParse(plyrNmsText, useInternalNodes=T)
plyrNmsCleaner <- trimws(unlist(xpathApply(plyrNmsClean, '//a', xmlValue)))
plyrNmsCleaner <- plyrNmsCleaner[!plyrNmsCleaner=='']
```

If you run this, you'll see that the list stops at Ben McLemore, even though there are 50+ names below. I tried this code yesterday as well and it still limited me to 28 names, which tells me the 28 isn't arbitrary.

What part of my code is preventing me from grabbing all names? I'm assuming it has to do with `findElement`, but I've tried a 100 different xpaths with the InspectorGadget html selector tool, and nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think nothing is wrong with your findElement expression. Is any exception thrown like ElementNotVisble?

Comment: No because technically the elements are visible, it's just not the whole list. I spent all day trying to figure it out, and what I found was that only 28 rows were ever being loaded on the site at once (as seen by inspecting table). As you scrolled up and down, new players/stats would fill those 28 boxes. So I used the exact code above, but I put it in a loop that scrolled down a little after each iteration. I complied each iteration into a dataframe and then removed duplicate rows. Extremely clunky but I'm happy that it worked.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. I wanted to have a look at the problem yesterday but the site was giving a warning that it was offline like it's also giving today. When the elements are visible from the start maybe it's a better idea to loop over the elements and to scroll them into view instead of scrolling a little bit down before you going to interact with them. How to do that in R I don't know but there must be a possibility for that.